# Nestjs/swagger open browser automatically like in REACT

Tags: browser, swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

I'd like my Nestjs/swagger application to start up as soon as bootstrap is finished

Initially I thought of using the callback of

```
async function bootstrap(): Promise<void> {
    console.clear();
    console.log("Starting and validating");

    const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {
        cors: true,
    });

    await app.listen(PORT, () => someOpenBrowserFuncion("/docs")`));
}
bootstrap();
```

*But I didn't find anything like that, so I thought*

When we start a *REACT* app, as soon as it is compiled, it opens the default browser automatically.
and
This option can be disabled with the following command:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "env BROWSER=none react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Is there a similar function in the **Nestjs/swagger** framework?

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "nest build",
  "dev": "nest start --watch",
  "start": "env BROWSER=true nest start",
  "production": "node dist/main",

},
```

Or some configuration to launch browser on certain endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a npm package `cross-env` : `npm install cross-env`

And update this command in the package.json file under '`scripts`';

```
"start": "cross-env BROWSER='chrome' nest start"
```

BROWSER is an environment variable, and you can use the `cross-env` package to properly handle it.

```
Linux:
 BROWSER='google-chrome-stable'
Windows:
 BROWSER='chrome'
OS X:
 BROWSER='google chrome'
```

If these don't work, you can update the script:

```
Windows:
"start": "start http://localhost:3000 & nest start"
Mac:
"start": "open http://localhost:3000 && nest start"
Linux:
"start": "xdg-open http://localhost:3000 && nest start"
```

You can change your own port number.

Comment: Doesn't work :(

Comment: What os do you use? Did you run `npm i cross-env`?

Comment: I have added another approach you can try

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately it was not the solution to my problem, since it did not generate the result I expected, but it helped a little. This answer was perfect for the proposal.

Answer (score 1):

I *really* wish Nest had a CLI flag for this, but I was able hack this together by using some native CLI commands. Since my personal goal was to add a `swagger` script that I could run to automatically open my Swagger docs in the browser, the resultant line in my `package.json`'s scripts section looks like this:

```json
"swagger": "( sleep 3 ; open 'http://localhost:3000/api' ) | nest start"
```

If you just want something to open the API in the browser whenever you start the Nest server, you could just edit the default `start` script to this:

```json
"start": "( sleep 3 ; open 'http://localhost:3000' ) | nest start"
```

The hyper-generalized version for opening anything in a browser after executing a Node command:

```bash
( sleep 3 ; open 'http://localhost:<YOUR_PORT>' ) | <SPECIFIC_NODE_COMMAND>
```

**Key Tricks**

- `sleep` command tells it to wait 3 seconds until trying to open it in the browser, since if I tried to open it automatically, the server wouldn't be up and running yet; a better approach instead of waiting exactly 3 seconds would be to periodically run curl commands every 1 second (or 0.5 seconds or whatever) and only try to open it in the browser once those commands don't fail, but I was feeling lazy
- `open` command tells it to open the specific URI, which should launch it in your default browser; as mentioned previously, I needed to use the sleep command to ensure this doesn't get run automatically
- `;` separates the delay command (`sleep`) from the key command (`open`)
- `(`  and  `)` commands (with spaces!) clarify that this entire section should be dealt with as a block operation
- `|` command uses or logic, so the script will first try the first block, which will "fail," so then it will move on to the second block, which will "succeed," but since the first block was still running in the background, it will eventually execute as well
- `nest start` command needs to go at the very end of all

I previously had tried to do `open 'http://localhost:3000/api' && nest start`, which would open it but before the server was built. That could work, but you would have to manually refresh the page, which is unideal. I also previously tried to do `nest start && open 'http://localhost:3000/api'`, but since `nest` is a Node command, everything after it doesn't fire.

Honestly, Nest should really have something like a `--openSwagger` flag to do this dynamically by reading the Swagger configs from `main.ts`, but hopefully this will suffice in the meantime!